# How to create Dataset from DataFrame column in Spark 2.0?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

Is it possible to create Dataset from Dataframe column in Spark 2.0?
I have a following issue: I want to read some data from parquet data partitioned by date and after that transform one of columns to Dataset.
Exmaple:

```
val frame = spark.read.parquet(path).select($"date", $"object".as[MyObjectType]).filter($"date" > "2016-10-01")
```

Now, I need to transform second column to `Dataset[MyObjectType]` and don't understand how i can do this. MyObjectType is scala product type

Answer (score 2):

You can do `cast`:

```
val frame = spark.read.parquet(path)
    .select($"date", $"object".cast(MyObjectTypeUDT))
    .filter($"date" > "2016-10-01")
```

In this case, MyObjectTypeUDT is one of SQL types, i.e. StringType or IntegerType or custom UserDefinedType.

Or, if you have some class which represents content in Dataset:

```
case clas DateWithObject (date : Timestamp, object: MyObject)
```

Then you can write:

```
val frame = spark.read.parquet(path)
    .select($"date", $"object")
    .as[DateWithObject] 
    .filter($"date" > "2016-10-01")
```

I  think it's the simplest way to do it